# Subnetting, networking, hosts?

Tags: subnet

my question is about subnet. Network is not allowed to be bigger than 15 000 machines. Which subnet should i use? Im looking at subnet calculator, but there aren't any subnets thats exactly 15 000 hosts. Either more or less. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

/18 netmask contains 16382 hosts/net.
So it is the closest match to your request.

/19 contains 8190 hosts/net so it does not fit your need.